# How to add a stored procedure to Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

Through SQL Developer, I added a *new stored procedure* to an Oracle database. Not only it is listed on the stored procedures list (along with every other SP) but I can easily execute it on SQL Developer.

The problem is I cannot seem to execute it from an external application. The database is linked to it, I can call every other stored procedure, but not the one I just created. The error message I get is:

**ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier 'SETDATE' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

I have copied access and permissions configs from other SPs that work, but it didn't really change anything.

Comment: Is your application connecting as the owner of the procedure? If not, is it being referenced as `user.procedure()`; and are the others that work? It sounds like you might have (perhaps public) synonyms of the other procedures but not your new one... assuming you have granted execute privileges properly as you state.

Comment: Is it really relevant? It does it's job when executed via SQL Developer.

Comment: you need the grants to execute it from the user.

Comment: @Rodrigo It makes a world of difference whether you are logged on as the owner or some different user. Please show the complete create procedure statement, as well as all grants you've given. Also, please provide the account you use with SQL Developer and the account you use with the external application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good thing when debugging this sort of thing is:

```
SELECT owner, object_name, object_type
FROM   all_objects
WHERE  object_name IN( 'PROCEDURE_WHICH_WORKS', 'PROCEDURE_WHICH_DOESNT' )
```

This should make it obvious if SQL*Developer created it in the wrong schema or there is a missing synonym or something like that. If its all the same then you need to look at possible missing GRANT EXECUTE permissions.

Are you sure SQL*Developer and your external program are connecting as exactly the same user? Just to be sure you can

```
SELECT user FROM dual
```